# Is it correct to say "will want"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I heard that we do not use the word 'want' after the word 'will'
because will includes the meaning 'wish'. But I saw lots of 
people using the expression like *no one will want to marry me*.

Comment: I'd like to know where you heard that.  "Will" *can* mean "wish", but it is unlikely that someone using "will want" is using "will" with that definition.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's perfectly correct. Here's some sentences you could use it in:

> No one will want to marry me.
>
> After being alone for so long, I will want to go home.
>
> We will want to rest after the long hike.

Whoever told you this didn't have a great argument. Sure, the word "will" can mean "wish", (although this is a rare usage) but lots of words have multiple meanings. Just because one of them might be wrong doesn't mean they all are.

Comment: It's actually pretty common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+want&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20want%3B%2Cc0